# SQL using mutiple selects when creating a view

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a view called customersummary that will have the customerID, firstname,lastname and the paper descriptions they are subscribed to
but it won't let me do 2 multiple select statements when creating the view, was wondering about other ways to do this
any help would be appreciated.

```
Create view CustomerSummary
as
Select  distinct customer.customerID,firstname,lastname from customer
inner join customerpaper on customer.customerID = CustomerPaper.PaperID
inner join paper on customerpaper.PaperID = paper.PaperId
where Description is not null
Select Description from paper where paperID is not null
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You could do a join or a union with paper. Most likely the former, but it's not clear from your question. Please add some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

In a view you can't set 2 select statement. To that you have to create a procedure

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE getCustomerSummaryByCustomerId
  @customerId INT
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT DISTINCT customer.customerID,firstname,lastname 
  FROM customer
  INNER JOIN customerpaper ON customer.customerID = CustomerPaper.PaperID
  INNER JOIN paper ON customerpaper.PaperID = paper.PaperId
  WHERE customer.customerId = @customerId

  SELECT p.Description FROM paper AS p
  WHERE p.paperID = @customerId
END
```

Example of call this procedure:

```sql
EXEC getCustomerSummaryByCustomerId @customerId = 1 /*or any other customer id*/
```

Note: Other option is create 2 different views

Answer (score 0):

To get basically the same results in a view, you might join the tables:

```
Create view CustomerSummary
as
Select  distinct c.customerID, c.firstname, c.lastname, cp.*, p.* 
from customer c
inner join customerpaper cp on c.customerID = cp.PaperID
inner join paper p on cp.PaperID = p.PaperId
where p.Description is not null
```

Note that I'm using table aliases to make the SQL a little more compact.